# Why is Android studio highlighting blocks of code?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

[image]

This is from AndroidManifest.xml

I've only shown a part of the file, but there are blocks of XML highlighted. What is this and how do I turn it off? it's really hurting my eyes :-)

Comment: hover with the mouse on it. It should give you a hint of what is missing/wrong.

Comment: ah ok, I need to actually hover on the right side at the start of the block

Comment: The highlighting was for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367875/android-adding-at-least-one-activity-with-an-action-view-intent-filler-after-u