# I have warning "App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter. "

Tags: java, android

After the update, the following warning appeared in the studio:
“App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding ACTION-VIEW intent filter. See issue explanation for more details. more ... (Ctrl + F1) »
How to fix it?

My Api is 28.

Here is my manifests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.omen.serverforcofe" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data  android:mimeType="text/plain"
                    />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367875/android-adding-at-least-one-activity-with-an-action-view-intent-filter-after-u

Answer (score 0):

```html
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>

       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Adding this intent filter to one of the activities declared in app manifest fixed this for me.