# What is the end result if I add ACTION-VIEW in my app?

Tags: android, google-search

I got this notification from my android studio:

> App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one
>   Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent-filler. See issue explanation for
>   more details.
>
> Adds deep links to get your app into the Google index, to get installs
>   and traffic to your app from Google Search.

Taking a look around Stackoverflow, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367875/android-adding-at-least-one-activity-with-an-action-view-intent-filter-after-u). Yes I get it, but how will it look like in Google Search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google app indexing is a warning in Android Studio that you can safely ignore. On enabling app indexing, Google will index your app so that it appears in **relevant** categories. But! It is designed to work with sites, meaning if a user searches for something and your website appears in the search and if you have app indexing on, then the **app will also appear with your website link**.

**Demo**:

[image: Indexing Sample]

Source: [searchengineland.com](https://searchengineland.com/library/google/google-app-indexing)

To enable deep linking on your app, you need to also go to:

1 - Sign into Play console

2 - Click on the app you want to enable deep linking

3 - Go to development tools section on the left.

4 - Go to Services&Apis

5 - Scroll to **App Indexing from Google Search** and verify the website.

Answer (score 2):

When your app is indexable by google, users can find it in relevant search results when your app isn't installed. This can help to increase your user base during the provided content.

[image: CNN sample of indexable content in android]

This link could also be useful to understand, if the effort is worth implementing it:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/01/case-study-app-indexing-google-worth-the-effort/